# facebook like button fetches wrong text

Tags: facebook

i am totally new on stackoverflow and i am pretty green in editing.
anyways maybe i can find some help here. i am running a blog
http://piecesofberlin.com - on every post u can find a facebook like button on the bottom,
and a share link on the right sidebar. i am using a wordpress fb likebutton plug in.
when i like a post the thumb nail of the picture and the title appears, but also
"You may use these HTML tags and attributes:
            " which is shown on the very bottom of the post....how can i get rid of it???

any ideas?

thx in advance
flo

Answer (score 0):

Ok - the information that the "send" button displays are to do with your og:tags.  Each post has to have a unique url (which it does becuase you managed to place different like buttons on each post).  The og:tags need to be present for each post too.  I see you placed the og:image tag only - you'll need more information.  You can user [this great took - URL Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to test your urls, and you can use [this reference - Open Graph Protocol](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) to see exactly what tags you must use.

Comment: sure man! no problem! if this post helps you out don't forget to mark this question as answered!:)